# LINQ to SQL Auto Inserting Row Copy When Updated

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-sql, exception

I am using this simple code to try and update a row

```
    var MyDB = new SKN2DataContext();
    var s_case = MyDB.SupportCases.FirstOrDefault(sc => sc.Id == 3);
    s_case.OpenDate = DateTime.Now;
    MyDB.SubmitChanges();
```

On the last line i am presented with the following exception

> Value of member 'Id' of an object of
>   type 'SupportCase' changed. A member
>   defining the identity of the object
>   cannot be changed. Consider adding a
>   new object with new identity and
>   deleting the existing one instead.

When I see what's going on by calling GetChangeList in QuickWatch, it says that the DataContext is trying to do and update (which i expect) as well as an insert of the same row (WHY???). I can't figure out why the DataContext is trying to do an insert.

**EDIT** Just for the record OpenDate is not included in the primary key.

Answer (score 0):

Is the `OpenDate` part of the primary key? I would look there first.

Is `s_case` not `null`?

Comment: I don't understand what u mean by s_case being 'not null'. Its just an object returned by my lambda expression. How is it supposed to be null or not null?

Comment: Well with `FirstOrDefault` I've seen it return `null`. Are you checking for this case?

Comment: Actually the exception is raised on the last line. Had it been the case u are suggesting, the exception would be raised on the second last line. And i know for a fact that it's not null

Answer (score 0):

- Isolate the code you are using, to make sure nothing else is causing it (like a shared context)
- Re-add the table in the linq2sql designer.